# Include bundle from multi (config) build

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

To optimize build perfomance i'm building app using two separate configs:
First bundle is more frequently changed, and thus second big-bundle content do not mess with the process of its rebuilding (because it they are in one config though they are different bundles, process of rebuilding only of the first still slows down).

```
configs = [
{ 
   entry: {app: './app'},
   output: ...
   plugins: [
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({..})
  ]
},
  // this is second rarely changed bundle
{
  entry: {big-bundle: './some/big'}.
  output: ...
}
]
```

As there only one index.html, it is plugged in one of the configs, the  question is how to include reference to `big-bundle` in resulting HTML, using HtmlWebpackPlugin if its name may be variable depending on hash?

Actually I have some ideas for solution using event hooks that are provided by HtmlWebpackPlugin. But I wonder if there will be other advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using the file-loader to load it into the correct location, combined with require.context?

You could use require.context to match the file name with a regular expression, and the file loader to copy the file over.

```
const context = require.context('./<the-files-directory>', false, /big-
bundle.*?\.js$/);
context.keys().forEach(key => context(key));
```

Then have a loader:

```
{
  test: /big-bundle.*?\.js$/,
  loader: 'file!name=<name for index.html>'
}
```